# .NET 4.5.1 hosting on .NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, .net-4.5

We are considering web development using .NET 4.5.1 (with VS 2013), EF6 and MVC 5.

Can we have this application hosted on a shared hosting service provider, which supports .NET 4.5, or do we need to wait for the service provider until they support .NET 4.5.1?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about choosing web hosting.

Comment: It is not about choosing web hosting.  It is a question about if we can deploy asp.net 4.5.1 applications on .net 4.5 runtime (just like we used to deploy asp.net 3.5 on .net 2.0 runtime)

Comment: Hmmm... I think I agree. I am reopening it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> .NET Framework 4 and 4.5 (including point releases such as 4.5.1):
>   "v4.0"

You should be able to run on 4.5.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. That article is talking about making something written in *older* versions run on the newer version instead. If only 4.5 is installed, there won't be some API's available which are from 4.5.1

Comment: If you use functionality that was added in 4.5.1 - that won't work. But if you're not using anything new than the app compiled against 4.5.1 will work on 4.5 framework the same way as 3.5 app can work on 2.0 framework (same version of CLR).